# 4-sum problem: my code selects four positive integers, while sum target is negative

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve the LeetCode problem [18. 4Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/description/):

> Given an array `nums` of `n` integers, return *an array of all the **unique** quadruplets* `[nums[a], nums[b], nums[c], nums[d]]` such that:
>
> - `0 <= a, b, c, d < n`
> - `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are **distinct**.
> - `nums[a] + nums[b] + nums[c] + nums[d] == target`
>
> You may return the answer in **any order**.

### Problem

Although I managed to pass several test cases, for the following input my code returns the wrong answer:

Input:

```
nums = [1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000]
target = -294967296
```

Expected output: `[]`

Output that my code produces: `[[1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000]]`

### My code

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        List<List<Integer>> quadriplets = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (nums.length < 4 || 4 * nums[0] > target || 4 * nums[nums.length - 1] < target){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=nums.length-4;i++){
            if(i==0 || nums[i] != nums[i-1]){
                for(int j=i+1;j<=nums.length-3;j++ ){
                    if(j==i+1 || nums[j] !=nums[j-1]){
                        int left=j+1 ,right=nums.length-1;
                        int targetSum=target-nums[i]-nums[j];
                        while(left<right){
                            if(nums[left]+nums[right]==targetSum){
                                List<Integer> quadt= new ArrayList<>();
                                quadt.add(nums[i]);
                                quadt.add(nums[j]);
                                quadt.add(nums[left]);
                                quadt.add(nums[right]);
                                quadriplets.add(quadt);
                                while(left<nums.length-1 && nums[left]==nums[left+1])left++;
                                while(right>0 && nums[right]==nums[right-1]) right--;
                                left++;
                                right--;
                            }
                            else if(nums[left]+nums[right] < targetSum){
                                left++;
                            }else{
                                right--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return quadriplets;
    }
}
```

### Question

I don't understand why this code generates that output. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi & Welcome! It's called "numerical overflow"... Since "natural numbers" can be arbitrary large ..."computer numbers" cannot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you encounter is caused by integer overflow. For the example test case, the expression `target-nums[i]-nums[j]` will evaluate to a positive number, even though `target` is negative and `nums[i]` and `nums[j]` are positive. A quick solution is to cast to `long`:

```
long targetSum=(long)target-nums[i]-nums[j];
```

This will fix the issue of the test case that failed. But there are more test cases, and overflow can also happen in the following expression:

```
4 * nums[0] > target || 4 * nums[nums.length - 1] < target
```

You can fix that by using `4L` instead of `4`:

```
4L * nums[0] > target || 4L * nums[nums.length - 1] < target
```

This corrected implementation will pass all the tests.